# Trying to deploy svelte vite application on digital ocean

Tags: javascript, svelte, digital-ocean, vite, svelte-3

i'm trying to deploy a svelte application on digital ocean using the default configuration, i only changed the run commande and the port, i keep getting :
Deploy Error: Health Checks

Answer (score 0):

i solve the same issue just creating an other componet in  but change to "web page" option to "static page".
it should look like this:

[image]